# flutter/firebase - The method XX was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and I am trying to integrate a firebase backend to store my data. I am trying to establish a stream using firebase but when I try to create a listview with the stream I get the following message:

```
The method 'collection' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: collection("betslips")
```

Here is my code:

```
  class Database {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  Database(this.firestore);

  Stream<List<BetSlipModel>> streamBetSlip({String uid}) {
    try {
      print(firestore.collection("betslips"));
      return firestore
          .collection("betslips")
          .snapshots()
          .map((query) {
            List<BetSlipModel> retVal;
            for(final DocumentSnapshot doc in query.docs) {
              retVal.add(BetSlipModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot: doc));
            }
            return retVal;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

I then try and access the values here:

```
body:  Expanded(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Database(widget.firestore)
        .streamBetSlip(uid: widget.auth.currentUser.uid),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<BetSlipModel>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Empty"),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return BetSlipCard(
              firestore: widget.firestore,
              uid: widget.auth.currentUser.uid,
              betslip: snapshot.data[index],
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: Text("loading..."),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if you dont assign a value to firestore, null.collection("betslips") will be happening,  null doesn't have any method

Comment: @TJMitch95 Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2):

> The method 'collection' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: collection("betslips")

means that `firestore` variable is not referencing anything, check the below on how to solve it:

You are creating an instance of the class here:

```
stream: Database(widget.firestore)
```

`widget` is an instance variable of the class `State`, therefore inside the `State` class initialize firestore:

```
final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```